# How to translate words in JS in multilingual website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation, nopcommerce

Am using nopCommerce, version 3.50. My site is multilingual: Russian, English, Espanol. There is a script for showing product images — magnific-popup.

So, when you click on photo it appears in a script box (like fancybox) and there are some titles like "Loading.., Close (Esc), Next, Previous, 1 of 2". They are always in English independingly on selected language at the website. I want it to be in a language which is selected.

How to do that?

There is a possibility to create strings in different languages giving them translations and put them in that jquery.magnific-popup.js file. A string looks like this — @T("magnificpopup.right"). But JS ignores strings, maybe because it is a separate script which does not touch this CMS.

```
options: {
    enabled: false,
    arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>',
    preload: [0,2],
    navigateByImgClick: true,
    arrows: true,

    tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)',
    tNext: '@T("magnificpopup.right")',
    tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
}
```

How can I set those strings correctly in JS file?
How can I solve my issue?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is documentation for Magnific popup l18n : http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#translating

According to it you should have in your JS code of the page **after** the line where the magnific-popup.js script is loaded.

```
var language = //you should get it from browser settings/cookies or server side

if(language == 'ru_RU'){

$.extend(true, $.magnificPopup.defaults, {
  tClose: 'Закрыть (Esc)', // Alt text on close button
  tLoading: 'Загрузка...', // Text that is displayed during loading. Can contain %curr% and %total% keys
//other lines 
  });

} else if (language == 'en_US'){

$.extend(true, $.magnificPopup.defaults, {
  tClose: 'Close (Esc)', // Alt text on close button
  tLoading: 'Loading...', // Text that is displayed during loading. Can contain %curr% and %total% keys
//other lines 
  });
} else if ( // other languages
```

Answer (score 1):

you must to create a simple object in your web site header,for example:

```
<script>
var mysite_lang = {
button_title: "<?php echo $lang['button_title'];?>",
box_title: "<?php echo $lang['box_title'];?>"
..etc..
};
</script>
```

after add your js files.

and now you can use

```
options: {
    enabled: false,
    arrowMarkup: '<button title="'+mysite_lang.button_title+'" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>'};
```

Comment: That does not work. Thank you for your trying to help.